Is there a way to force an application to use a specific network adapter / bind to a specific IP?
I run a VPN on my system, and using my system routing table, I can route traffic to specific outgoing IP addresses either through the VPN's utun network interface or through my ethernet adapter normally.
However, I'm wondering if it's possible for me to force certain applications to always bind to a specific network interface / IP address when making network connections, so that it either only uses the VPN or only uses my ethernet adapter, regardless of what's in the system routing table.
Put another way, I'm looking for a macOS alternative to ForceBindIP.
Is that possible?

Do these applications support web proxies as a setting?


You need to specify your VPN product and which applications. 2) A few VPN products (e.g. PIA) provide application level routing (split tunnelling).


@bmike One of the applications I'm working with is Firefox, which does support web proxies. I thought that one solution for it specifically would be to run a proxy server locally that binds to a specific interface, and then configure Firefox to use the proxy. But I'm wondering if there's a more generalizable way to do it for apps that doesn't have their own proxy setting.

@Gilby I'm experimenting with a few different VPN clients but none of them support split tunneling on a per-application basis. And one of my use cases is setting up an application to only use the VPN interface so that its network connections fail when the VPN isn't connected, while other applications will still function. That's not generally possible with per-application split tunneling.

Private Internet Access has split tunnelling by application. That is what I use.
